# toast not working in my Samsung Fame, but work on others

Tags: android, toast

In my Samsung fame, my app won't display any Toast ( Before it was working)
Now, I tried with HTC Nexus One, and Samsung S3 Mini, and for the same app, both are displaying well Toasts.

I just don't know if there's a problem with my cel, or if a lot of cels can't see Toasts.

Do you have any idea of what can provoque this kind of problem???

Comment: It happens with different devices behave differently, try to debug the code by placing Log.i(tag, "") to check if it enters in the code you looking for

Comment: I think it is not a problem of code, Log enter everywhere it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Jelly Bean 4.1 or higher,you can disable apps notifications from device settings. Just open notification bar, long tap on any of notifications and click App Info, you should see “Show notifications”. Unchecking this option should disable toasts in your app.

If your app does not show any notifications, then you should be able to reach App Info screen from applications manager.

Maybe this is the cause of you missing toasts